# How to use a user defined exceptions in java inside another method

Tags: java, exception

I want to create a set method to insert maximum temperature for a specific place and I want that temperature to be of type Double,the method will check if the entered number is >= to 100 or <= to 100
if yes then it will be inserted in the maximum temperature field..
else I have to throw a user defined exception that will tell me that the number I entered is out of the supposed limits!

I wrote the Exception and the method this way:

```
public class OutOfSensibleLimits extends Exception
{
private Double max;
public OutOfSensibleLimits(Double max)
  {
this.max = max;
  }
public Double getMax()
 {
return max;
 }
public String toString()
  {
return "The maximum Tempreture you entered: '" + maxTemp +
"' is out of sensible limits.";
  }
}



public void setMaxTemp(Double max){

   if ( max >= -100 || max <= 100)
   {
      maxTemp = max;
   }
    else throw new OutOfSensibleLimits();
       }
```

and it gives me an error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please note changes to answer. In the future, please post any and all full error messages and exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

1. This is not how exceptions work -- you need to call the appropriate super constructor with the appropriate String if you want it to show a String, and
2. You're not calling your own exception's constructor properly. You've written it to accept a Double, and you're not passing in a Double (you're passing in nothing).
3. the `toString` method is unnecessary and confusing since it will never be called and the String will never be seen.
4. You state, `"and it gives me an error,..."`, but don't show us any error message. I'm guessing that the compiler is complaining that you're not calling your class's constructor correctly, but please don't leave us guessing -- **show the complete unabridged error message**.
5. Your setMaxTemp uses the wrong boolean operator: `if ( max >= -100 || max <= 100)`. This is **always** true. You want to use `&&` instead.

Suggestions:

- Yes, pass in a double the constructor
- And then use that double to create an appropriate error/exception message that is passed into the super's constructor.
- Get rid of your exception class's fields and `toString()` method.
- Most important, I urge you to first read the [Exception tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) before trying anything else.
- Also simplify as you're making things overly complex. Your Exception class could easily be nothing more than a constructor and that's it.
- Make sure that the method that might throw the exception declares that it throws this exception.

For example:

```
public class TestSensibleLimits {
    private Double maxTemp;

    public void setMaxTemp(double max) throws OutOfSensibleLimits {
        if (max >= -100 && max <= 100) { // use && not ||
            maxTemp = max;
        } else
            throw new OutOfSensibleLimits(max);
    }

    public Double getMaxTemp() {
        return maxTemp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestSensibleLimits test = new TestSensibleLimits();
        try {
            test.setMaxTemp(200);
        } catch (OutOfSensibleLimits e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class OutOfSensibleLimits extends Exception {
    private static final String FORMAT = "The maximum Temperature you "
            + "entered: %.2f is out of sensible limits.";

    public OutOfSensibleLimits(Double max) {
        super(String.format(FORMAT, max));
    }
}
```

Comment: @MaramAl-Zu'bi: [String#format(...) API entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).